# Como recuperar dados da sessão além do ID

Tags: php, javascript

Estou criando uma sessão no PHP e pegando o ID dela com cookie via javascript, porém eu gostaria de saber com eu faço para pegar outros dados além do ID, como o nome da sessão por exemplo.

### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### login.php:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['nome'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = "Minha Sessao";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Usuário Logado:<p id='teste'></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var usuario = document.cookie;
        alert(usuario);
        document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML = usuario;
    </script>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### logout.php:

```
<?php

  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['sessao']))
  {
    echo 'Não existe uma sessão para ser encerrada';
  }else{                                                            
    header("location:index.html"); 
  } 

?>
```

Comment: Sessão é algo exclusivo do servidor. Você não consegue acessar a sessão via JS, precisará fazer isso por PHP, tal como fez utilizando `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score -1):

Dá um print de tudo na session:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Aí é só usar o que você precisa.

Answer (score -1):

nunca use sem efetuar a inicialização da sessão.

```php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
```

O mais correto é

```php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
```

Para você verificar o conteúdo das variáveis padrões do PHP basta fazer a impressão utilizando

```php
var_dump($_SESSION)

//ou

print_r($_SESSION)
```

Você pode utilizar também com $_GET, $_POST, etc..